# use capistrano after delete heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku, capistrano

I had a rails app that's was running on heroku, I recently got my VPS and trying to move it to my own server.

So, I deleted my heroku, and added an origin.

I did all the setups for deploy.rb(all looks fine)

but when I run cap deploy:setup, I got:

```
* 2012-11-24 20:35:21 executing `deploy:setup'
* executing "mkdir -p /var/www/sites/phil88530.com /var/www/sites/phil88530.com/releases /var/www/sites/phil88530.com/shared /var/www/sites/phil88530.com/shared/system /var/www/sites/phil88530.com/shared/log /var/www/sites/phil88530.com/shared/pids"
servers: ["phil88530.com"]
[phil88530.com] executing command
*** [err :: phil88530.com] 
*** [err :: phil88530.com] !  Invalid path.
*** [err :: phil88530.com] 
*** [err :: phil88530.com] !  Syntax is: git@heroku.com:<app>.git where <app> is your app's name.
command finished in 956ms
```

I don't want heroku exist anymore, why does it ask for heroku?

And I don't understand the invalid path as well, would be nice if I capistrano can get me more informatinos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://phil88530.com/ resolves to heroku... so when capistrano connects to `servers: ["phil88530.com"]`, it's connecting to heroku.

You can either set the server to the IP address of your new VPS, or move the DNS over to the new VPS to correct the problem.

Comment: oh that's brilliant ! thought I can do it later since I have defined the deploy spec the VPS. thank you! I will change my DNS now